# How to generate a 3d ROI sphere in a specific location within a 3d file (python / nilearn)

Tags: python, image, 3d, masking, roi

My aim is to mask a 3D image at a given location with a 3d spherical mask.
I want to extract all of the values of the image within this 3D mask

I am currently using python's nilearn.image.NiftiSpheresMasker function to achieve this in the following way:

```
central_coordinates=(x,y,z)
masker = NiftiSpheresMasker(central_coordinates, radius=rad)
values=masker.fit_transform(resampled_image)
```

However, this only returns the mean signal within the ROI. Is there a way to either:

- Extract the mask that this function uses (so that I can obtain the values manually)
- Use an alternative method to achieve this 3D ROI

P.s I have already tried using FSL's `fslmaths -kernel` which works for cubes but not spheres.

Comment: What does your 3d image look like? Is it just a 3d numpy array, a 3-tuple list or something else?

Comment: Yes it is a 3d numpy array :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using  the function `create_sphere` from the package nltools

See this link: https://github.com/ljchang/nltools/issues/122